# iphone - apply CGAffineTransformRotate on point in hittest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation

I've got an image that's allowed to be rotated and scaled by the user.
Every time the user clicks the image I try to figure out if the point is transparent or not.

If it's transparent I return null in my view's HitTest, if it's not transparent I return the view. Problems start when user rotates the image. In my hitTest method, I need to transform the point according to the current view's rotation. Otherwise the point will indicate an irrelevant location on the view (and the image).

How do I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [CGAffineTransform Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) might help:

```
CGPointApplyAffineTransform

CGRectApplyAffineTransform
```

and

```
CGSizeApplyAffineTransform
```

But before you start thinking that you need to perform the mapping by hand, I would suggest to give it a try 'as if' the current transformation was CGAffineIdentity, and code your coordinate detection accordingly. You might be surprised by the results ...

My own experience says that it looks like when you get your points from UITouch locationIn_SomeView_ the inverted matrix of *SomeView* is applied to the point before it is handed back to you.

So, you probably don't need any of the CGxxxApplyAffineTransform unless you generate the points yourself, outside of the events system.

Comment: Great, thank you! Actually, I have been given the uiview's coordinate system a chance. But since I am checking the color of a particular pixel in the image, it seems it's not enough.

Comment: In my case, it is. I have a non rectangular image (rounded triangle like) with fully transparent pixels everywhere but inside the triangle itself. And I wanted my touch detection to not trigger on the "transparent" pixels. So I did what you say, ie: I get at the pixel coordinate of the image *whose rectangular bounds* is aligned with the view bounds. If we ignore the "retina scaling factor" for a minute, any point within the view bounds maps directly into a pixel in the image. EVEN WHEN THE VIEW IS ROTATED

Comment: Actually you're right! I just gave it a try. You say it might not work in ratina mode though?

Comment: Well, at the stage when you get the actual pixels for the image, you should take the scale into account. On non-retina displays, 1 screen coordinate point is one pixel. On a retina display 1 screen point is 4 pixels. You should get the scale from the UIDevice, and assuming you have a "2x" image, transform your screen point using that scale to reach the desired pixel image.

Comment: I meant so say: [UIScreen mainScreen].scale ;